# CRM - Retrieve Selected Option Set From Another Form

Tags: javascript, sdk, dynamics-crm-2013

In my quotes form the user will input the 'potential customer' when this is done I want to be able to retrieve what option has been selected from a option set from the account form and put the text into a text field in the quotes form.

So far I have the following JS;

```
    var entityLogicalName= "account";
    var RetrieveAttributeName= "paymenttermscode";

    SDK.MetaData.RetrieveEntityAsync(SDK.MetaData.EntityFilters.Attributes,entityLogicalName, null, false,
    function (entityMetadata)
    {
      onSuccess(entityLogicalName, entityMetadata, RetrieveAttributeName); 
    }, 
    onError);


function onSuccess(logicalName, entityMetadata, RetrieveAttributeName)
{
 for(var i=0; i<entityMetadata.Attributes.length;i++)
 {
  var AttributeMetadata = entityMetadata.Attributes[i];
  if (success) break;
  if (AttributeMetadata.SchemaName.toLowerCase() ==RetrieveAttributeName.toLowerCase())
  {
    for (var o = 0; o<AttributeMetaData.OptionSet.Options.length; o++)
    {
      var option = AttributeMetadata.OptionSet.Options[o];
      if(option.OptionMetadata!=null&&option.OptionMetadata.Label!=null)
      {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_paymentterms").setValue(option.OptionMetadata.Label.UserLocalizedLabel.Label);

      break;
      }
    }
  }
 }
}

function onError(XmlHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown)
{
  alert(errorThrown);
}
```

However I keep getting an error message stating

Unable to get property RetrieveEntityAsync of undefined or null reference

Is this because I am trying to retrieve data from another form?
Does anyone know a solution to this problem, thank you

**UPDATE**

Turns out as I am using Internet Explorer that the function XPathEvaluator within the SDK.Metadata.js is causing an error as it is no longer supported

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Are you referencing the library SDK.MetaData.js in your Quote form? It sounds like it is missing or at least not loaded at the time you are trying to execute the function.

Comment: Turns out although I clicked to upload the SDK nothing had actually gone through, so I ended up with a blank resource, I tried again and no error message, however nothing has gone into my text field

Comment: Your current code doesn't show the function you are using as the OnChange event handler for your "Potential Customer" attribute. You'll need to debug using the developer tools in IE to see what's going on.

Comment: @Filburt Upon investigation it appears that the function onSuccess is not running at all, any suggestions?

Comment: @Filburt From debugging I have come across an error in the SDK.Metadata where an error is being from because ' XPathEvaluator' is undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using XPathEvaluator and IE-specific XML functions (like selectSingleNode) is to use jQuery's selectors for XML, which XrmServiceToolkit uses. See the link below.

https://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Can you give further details please? I have used this tool for Odata, which I did start using to complete this problem of mine, however the OData query would only return two arrays and therefore I started going down this path which seems like it should work.

Comment: You could use syntax like jQuery("b\\:value, value").text() or $(b\\:value, value").text(). Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no RetrieveEntityAsync() function in the official SDK.Metadata.js library.  Did you write that yourself?  Or get that library from somewhere online?

Either way, just call the standard SDK.Metadata.RetrieveEntity() function, it is asynchronous, and it works just fine in IE.

Also, if you are declaring entityLogicalName and RetrieveAttributeName globabally, then you don't need to pass them to the onSucess method, they will already be available there.